# Mark Multiple Data Info as NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 - here is my query. It works perfectly except I want to add states. The issue with adding states is that the 'No Zone' zones can technically be apart of multiple states, so for `No Zones`, I'd just like to mark that section as `'NULL'`

Is there some sort of statement to say -

```
if z.Zonename = 'NO zone' then st.Stateshortcode = Null   ?
```

Tried using `CASE` but that seems to give me some trouble.

```
DECLARE @BulkInfo TABLE (
    ZoneID INT,
    ZoneName VARCHAR(100),
    StateID INT,
    StateShortCode VARCHAR(5),
    SiteID BIGINT,
    SiteEveGID INT,
    Papers BIGINT
    );

INSERT INTO @BulkInfo (ZoneID, ZoneName, StateID, StateShortCode, SiteID, SiteEveGID, Papers)
SELECT 
    z.ZoneID,
    ISNULL(z.ZoneName,'NO ZONE'),
    CASE WHEN st.StateID is null THEN 0 END /** Just screwing around here **/,
    st.StateShortCode,
    s.SiteID,
    wfset.SiteEveGID,
    COUNT(c.PaperID) Papers
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteLocation sl ON s.SiteID = sl.SiteID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.States st ON sl.StateID=st.StateID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Zones z ON sl.ZoneID = z.ZoneID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEves wfse ON s.SiteID = wfse.SiteID AND EveStatusID IN (1,2)
LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEveTs wfset ON wfse.EveTID = wfset.EveTID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Papers c ON s.SiteID = c.SiteID
WHERE
    s.ProjID = 1
GROUP BY 
    z.ZoneID,
    z.ZoneName,
    st.StateID,
    st.StateShortCode,
    s.SiteID,
    wfset.SiteEveGID,
    wfse.EveTID

SELECT 
    t.ZoneName,
    t.StateShortCode,
    TotalSites,
    TotalPapers,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),TotPer) 'TotPer%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesPart1, 0) TotalSitesPart1,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersPart1, 0) TotalPapersPart1,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Part1Per),0) 'Part1Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesPart2,0) TotalSitesPart2,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersPart2,0) TotalPapersPart2,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Part2Per),0) 'Part2Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesPart3, 0) TotalSitesPart3,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersPart3, 0) TotalPapersPart3,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Part3Per),0) 'Part3Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesPart4,0) TotalSitesPart4,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersPart4,0) TotalPapersPart4,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Part4Per),0) 'Part4Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesPart5,0) TotalSitesPart5,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersPart5,0) TotalPapersPart5,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Part5Per),0) 'Part5Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesPart6,0) TotalSitesPart6,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersPart6,0) TotalPapersPart6,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Part6Per),0) 'Part6Per%',
    ISNULL(TotalSitesPart7,0) TotalSitesPart7,
    ISNULL(TotalPapersPart7,0) TotalPapersPart7,
    ISNULL(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),Part7Per),0) 'Part7Per%'
FROM 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSites,
    SUM(Papers) TotalPapers,
    SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) TotPer
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) t
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSitesPart1,
    SUM(Papers) TotalPapersPart1,
   SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Part1Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteEveGID = 2
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) f ON t.ZoneName = f.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSitesPart2,
    SUM(Papers) TotalPapersPart2,
    SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Part2Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteEveGID = 2
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) o ON t.ZoneName = o.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSitesPart3,
    SUM(Papers) TotalPapersPart3,
    SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Part3Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteEveGID = 4
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) fm ON t.ZoneName = fm.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSitesPart4,
    SUM(Papers) TotalPapersPart4,
    SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Part4Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteEveGID = 6
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) r ON t.ZoneName = r.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSitesPart5,
    SUM(Papers) TotalPapersPart5,
    SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Part5Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteEveGID = 7
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) cs ON t.ZoneName = cs.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSitesPart6,
    SUM(Papers) TotalPapersPart6,
    SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Part6Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteEveGID = 9
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) d ON t.ZoneName = d.ZoneName
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
    ZoneName,
    StateShortCode,
    COUNT(SiteID) TotalSitesPart7,
    SUM(Papers) TotalChartsPart7,
    SUM(Papers)*100.0/(SELECT SUM(Papers) FROM @BulkInfo) Part7Per
FROM 
    @BulkInfo
WHERE 
    SiteEveGID = 8
GROUP BY ZoneName,StateShortCode) m ON t.ZoneName = m.ZoneName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this logic:

```
(case when z.ZoneName is not null then st.StateShortCode end) as StateShortCode
```

If it can take on the value "No Zone", then:

```
(case when z.ZoneName is not null and z.ZoneName <> 'No Zone'
      then st.StateShortCode
 end) as StateShortCode
```

Comment: The second mini code is actually what I was looking for - just needed to add the ELSE at the end in order to get the issue I had corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there some sort of statement to say - if z.Zonename=NO zone then st.Stateshortcode=Null??

sure there is:

```
update tablename st
join othertable z on z.join_col=st.join_col
set st.Stateshortcode=null
where z.Zonename='NO ZONE'
```

however, if you are already doing a big update maybe a case statement is what you need:

```
...
INSERT INTO @BulkInfo (ZoneID, ZoneName, StateID, StateShortCode, SiteID, SiteEveGID, Papers)
SELECT 
    z.ZoneID,
    ISNULL(z.ZoneName,'NO ZONE'),
    CASE WHEN st.StateID is null THEN 0 END /** Just screwing around here **/,
    case when z.ZoneName is null then null else st.StateShortCode end,
    s.SiteID,
    wfset.SiteEveGID,
    COUNT(c.PaperID) Papers
FROM 
    dbo.Sites s 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SiteLocation sl ON s.SiteID = sl.SiteID
...
```